# Raspberry Pi 4b v1.1 k8s cluster USB hub power supply

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, cluster-computing, raspberry-pi4

I'm planning on building a cluster of 5 or more rpi4b (v1.1).

Tutorial for that: [Build a Raspberry Pi Cluster Computer](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/build-a-raspberry-pi-cluster-computer)

All is fine and dandy except for the power supply for all the units.
I have no intention of having individual cords from each unit to the wall, so I thought of a USB hub power supply with multiple ports. This would also allow me to increase the unit count in the future will less hassle.
Also, assume an ethernet cable and a small SSD drive connected via USB per unit. No screen or HID device connected.

What would be a good fit for running the cluster 24/7?

I thought of these:

- [IWAIVON USB Wall Charger](http://iwavion.com/product.php?name=661585019780-)
- [Anker PowerPort Speed 4 Port](https://www.anker.com/products/variant/powerport-speed-4-ports/A2040111)
- [Anker PowerPort 10](https://www.anker.com/products/variant/powerport-10/A2133111)
- [RavPower Prime 60W 6 Port](https://www.ravpower.com/products/rp-pc028-60w-usb-charger)

Assuming that every USB port in the hub will be (eventually) connected and having in mind that RaspberryPi4B v1.1 specs states that it requires a 5v/3A power supply which none of these supply, what will be a good USB hub power supply? It doesn't have to be one I listed...